# Getting mouse position in major internet browsers with javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup, mouse, position

I read this article regarding creating [popup notes with javascript and css](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Creating-PopUp-Notes-with-CSS-and-JavaScript-Part-I/2/)

The problem is that this one works only in IE since window.event is undefined in Firefox.

```
// assigns X,Y mouse coordinates to note element
note.style.left=event.clientX;
note.style.top=event.clientY;
```

So could you point me a fully working example? Or at least, how could i modify the javascript code to make it work in both internet browsers?

Comment: Most browsers pass the event object as a parameter to the handler function, rather than making it available as `windows.event`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more than two browsers, but the following should work in most of them (adapted from the function on the page you linked to):

```
showNote = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    // gets note1 element
    var note1=document.getElementById('note1');
    // assigns X,Y mouse coordinates to 'note1' element
    note1.style.left=evt.clientX;
    note1.style.top=evt.clientY;
    // makes note1 element visible
    note1.style.visibility='visible';
};
```

The problem is that not all browsers have an `event` property of `window` and instead use an event object implicitly passed in as a parameter to an event handler function such as `showNote`. The `evt = evt || window.event;` line assigns `window.event` to the `evt` variable if no event parameter was passed into the function (which is what happens in Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the two branches when you define the method.
It takes more characters than bundling them together,
but you do not have to check for support on every every call.

//

```
window.whereAt= (function(){
    var fun;
    if(typeof pageXOffset== 'number'){
        fun= function(e){
            var pX, pY, sX, sY;

            pX= e.clientX || 0;
            pY= e.clientY || 0;
            sX= window.pageXOffset;
            sY= window.pageYOffset;
            return [(pX+sX), (pY+sY)];
        }
    }
    else{
        fun= function(e){
            e= (e && e.clientX)? e: window.event;
            var pX, pY, sX, sY;

            pX= (e.clientX);
            pY= (e.clientY);
            var d= document.documentElement;
            var b= document.body;
            sX= Math.max(d.scrollLeft, b.scrollLeft);
            sY= Math.max(d.scrollTop, b.scrollTop);
            var pwot= [(pX+sX), (pY+sY)];
            return pwot;
        }
    }
    return fun;
})()
//test case
document.ondblclick= function(ev){
    alert(whereAt(ev))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, but using canvas.addEventListener instead of onclick funion bind in attributes of canvas. And it works in IE, FF, Chrome.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
function ev_mousedown(ev){
    var posx=0;posy=0;
    if (e.offsetX > 0) { // IE, Chrome
        posx = e.offsetX;
        posy = e.offsetY;
    } else{ // Firefox
        posx = e.layerX;
        posy = e.layerY;
    }
 } // This also works correctly while zoom!=100%

<div style="position: relative;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" onClick="newClick()" style="position: relative;"></canvas>
</div>
```

See reference: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

---

The following codes doesn't work in Firefox.

```
showNote = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    // gets note1 element
    var note1=document.getElementById('note1');
    // assigns X,Y mouse coordinates to 'note1' element
    note1.style.left=evt.clientX;
    note1.style.top=evt.clientY;
    // makes note1 element visible
    note1.style.visibility='visible'
}
```

I have google for many solutions and referenced the relatively official site for browers differs: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos

But still have not found a solution in Firefox 20.
window.event has no definition in FF. But works well in IE and Chrome.

I wonder have I misunderstood something in this point?